# Disable modal in jhipster/angular ui

Tags: angularjs, jhipster

I would like to disable modal dialogs in a jhipster generated application in favor of elements displayed in page.

See https://github.com/jhipster/generator-jhipster/issues/2693

Comment: why not implementing the edit/new page the same way as currently done with the normal pages?

Answer (score 2):

You should make it just like the "-detail" state right above. Make a block like

```
views: {
    'content@': {
        templateUrl: 'app/entities/smthn/smthn-dialog.html',
        controller: 'SmthnDialogController',
        controllerAs: 'vm'
    }
},
```

after `data` object and move `resolve` out of the `$uibModal.open`.
Then there is a bit of change in your controller.
Make `clear` function look like that:

```
function clear () {
    $state.go('^');
}
```

and replace `$uibModalInstance.close(result);` with `$state.go('smthn', {}, { reload: 'smthn' });` in `onSaveSuccess`.

Comment: How I would disable in newest jhipster4/angular ui 2?