# Jhipster 4 replacing NgbModal with HTML view

Tags: angular, angular2-routing, angular2-modal

I am trying to understand the necessary changes to make in a generated jhipster app to replace the NgbModals with elements displayed in a page.
I was able to find some [help](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40424898/disable-modal-in-jhipster-angular-ui) on doing this in older Jhipster versions with angular 1.x but I am unable to make the changes in Jhipster v4.0.2 and angular 2. 
I tried repurposing the detail component and map it to the route -new path (for add new record), but getting an error for undefined "id" parameter.
I am looking for some pointers for the approach to take  for solving this problem.

Thank you !

Comment: Show some code; in particular what you modified in your routes.

Comment: @GaëlMarziou. I apologize for the delayed response. [link] (https://gist.github.com/udaystartup/859e533f96de83bfda116d6261d6884e) address-type-route.ts   [link](https://gist.github.com/udaystartup/edbf39309bd9c34ca1bee797afd1be5f) address-type.component.html   and [link](https://gist.github.com/udaystartup/f8000954d2f90c4af6fcce774b0690e4) address-type.create.component.ts.  The save is working fine, the edit and automatically navigating to the list of address-types is not working as I want it to. I am fairly new to angular 2 and trying to tweak code to understand the working.

Comment: Have you tried setting `pathMatch: full` on some of your routes?